# ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 156: Trying to get property of non-object laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-middleware

I am getting this error when I created my own middleware and used it

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $privilege = $request->session()->has('privilege');

    if($request->session()->has('privilege'))
    {
        if($privilege == "Owner" || $privilege == "owner")
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['privilege_check' => "You are not privileged to go there!."]);
        }
    }
    return '/home';
}
```

Comment: Which is line 156?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you haven't set the `session('privilege')`. If you have already set it up then close down the browser and run the application again from start. It maybe did not set up during the development.

Answer (score 3):

**Check this**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        if(Session::get('user_id') == NULL)
        {
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }else{
            return $next($request);
        }
    });
}
```